# Why do I get different argument types when using filter on an iterator?

Tags: filter, rust, reference, iterator, closures

I'm using `filter`, but I don't understand why I should use `**x > 1` for a slice but use `*x > 1` for a range.

```
fn main() {
    let a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    let a_iter = a.iter().filter(|x: &&i32| **x > 1);  // x: &&i32
    let x: Vec<&i32> = a_iter.collect();
    println!("{:?}", x);

    let b = 0..4;
    let b_iter = b.filter(|x: &i32| *x > 1);           // x: &i32
    let y: Vec<i32> = b_iter.collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

[The docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) say it should be `**x > 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`slice::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), such as `a.iter()` in your example, produces an iterator over references to values. `Range`s are iterators that produce non-reference values.

The [`filter(<closure>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) method takes a `<closure>` that takes iterator values by reference, so if your iterator already produces references you'll get a reference to a reference, and if your iterator produces non-reference values then you'll get references to those values.

The difference becomes easier to understand if we use a `Vec` for both examples:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
    let a_iter = a.iter(); // iter() returns iterator over references
    let x: Vec<&i32> = a_iter.filter(|x: &&i32| **x > 1).collect();
    println!("{:?}", x);

    let b = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
    let b_iter = a.into_iter(); // into_iter() returns iterator over values
    let y: Vec<i32> = b_iter.filter(|x: &i32| *x > 1).collect();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=193cd06b02f779e6173ee6fdda4177a3)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the array-example, you first call `.iter()` to create an iterator, which borrows the array and hence to values in it; the closure-argument to `filter` receives a borrowed version of the iterator's `Item`, so it's borrowed again, which makes it a `&&i32`.

In the `Range`-case, you call `filter` directly, as a `Range` *is* an iterator. The iterator, therefore, contains owned values and the closure in `filter` borrows that, which makes its type `&i32`.

You can see that if you try to `let y = b;` after the `let b_iter = ...`-line: You'll get a `use of moved value`-error because `b` was consumed by the iterator you used in `b.filter`